# Why is KeePass2 not in the AppCenter?

Tags: release-loki, appcenter

I work with KeePass2 on Linux (and Windows) voor quite some time. It's available for Ubuntu and LinuxMint, why isn't it in the AppCenter for ElementaryOS? We (=the familie & our small business company) really miss it!

Arnold

Comment: There are many applications not included in AppCenter. It will be endless discussing personal choices. The developers goal is picking software that integrates well in elementary environment. In any case if you find KeePass2 a must you can try the following link: https://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/xenial/universe/k/keepass2/install/index.html

Comment: @JorgeR.Marín I feel that this should be an answer not a comment - it is succinct and provides a working alternative!

Comment: Published as an answer. Thanks for the suggestion Mike Wild.

Answer (score 3):

There are many applications not included in AppCenter. It will be endless discussing personal choices. The developers goal is picking software that integrates well in elementary environment. In any case if you find KeePass2 a must you can try the following link: https://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/xenial/universe/k/keepass2/install/index.html

Answer (score 2):

KeePass2 is missing in AppCenter because `keepass2` package doesn't supply AppStream metadata. You need to contact KeePass2 developers and inform them of this issue or just wait until someone will report about this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Synaptic package manager instead of App Center. It's a different program to manage the packages that the OS and the programs you use are composed of. In Synaptic you'll find Keepass2 and other stuff that is not included in AppCenter. To install synaptic, you can use AppCenter (just search for "synaptic") or Terminal by typing:

sudo apt install synaptic

Once you have opened Synaptic you'll find a search box at the top. If you search for keepass, you'll get a list of all packages that include that term, including KeePass2 and KeePassX. To install, right-click on the preferred package and choose install in the contextual menu. This will mark the package for installation. You can then search for other (unrelated) packages you might want to install too and also mark them. To finally install everything, you have to click on the "apply" icon at the top of the window. Then everything you have marked for installation will be installed.

Comment: This answer should be expanded to explain *what* Synaptic is, how the user would install it, and how they can then install Keepass. As it stands I believe it is incomplete.

Comment: Hey guys, Thanks for the answers. I decided to reinstall Synaptic and Keepass. It works. Thank you very much :-) Arnold